# Map an array of class's to only return a certain set of properties

Tags: javascript

I have got an array of class instances, however I need to run through all of these and return a certain set of properties from the classes:

```js
class Checkbox {
    constructor() {
        this.test1 = 'dsdas';
        this.test2 = 'dsdas';
        this.test3 = 'dsdas';
        this.test4 = 'dsdas';
    }
    onlySome() {
        return {
            test3: this.test3 || null,
            test4: this.test4 || null,
        }
    }
}

const fields = {
    class1: Checkbox,
    class2: Checkbox,
    class3: Checkbox,
    class4: Checkbox,
}

const filtered = fields.map(value => value.onlySome());
```

The map doesn't work, what is the best way to do this, the code should make sense as to what i'm trying to do?

So `filtered` would be something like:

```js
const filtered = {
    class1: <Checkbox>{
        test3: dsdas,
        test4: dsdas,
    }
}
```

Above is just example code, it doesn't function! Just trying to show what i'm trying to do!

Comment: `fields` is an object, `.map()` a method of `Array`. Why should this work?

Comment: What @Andreas said is true. `field` is an object, so filter will not work.

Comment: `class1: <Checkbox>` - `class1` is not of type `Checkbox` when there's only a subset of the properties of `Checkbox` in it

Comment: `Map` is my attempt and example of what I want, I know it doesn't work. And I know it's a subset, i'm just showing the kinda structure I want to have back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for, Use `Object.keys` then use `map` since it is an object.

```js
class Checkbox {
    constructor() {
        this.test1 = 'dsdas';
        this.test2 = 'dsdas';
        this.test3 = 'dsdas';
        this.test4 = 'dsdas';
    }
    onlySome() {
        return {
            test3: this.test3 || null,
            test4: this.test4 || null,
        }
    }
}

const fields = {
    class1: new Checkbox(), //instantiate it first
    class2: new Checkbox(), //instantiate it first
    class3: new Checkbox(), //instantiate it first
    class4: new Checkbox(), //instantiate it first
}

const filtered = Object.keys(fields).map(key => {
    return {
        [key]: fields[key].onlySome()
    }
});

console.log(filtered);
```